# Force GitHub pages to render numerical lists sequentially instead of restarting?

Tags: github, github-pages, mkdocs

I noticed that when GitHub pages with mkdocs have text or images in between numbers it ignores the numbering in the source document and instead restarts numbering. See [here](https://grantcurell.github.io/Make%20USB%20Read%20Only/) for an example of this.

Is there a way to force mkdocs to render the numbers in the original document instead of inventing its own?

Answer (score 0):

If you add them all as 1. space and text, then sub item as image with a tab, it should work. As an example:

```
1. Option 1
    imgage or next text
1. Option 2
```

You can check this [documentation](https://docs.mindsdb.com/#quickstart-guide) built using mkdocs as an example.

Answer (score 0):

As Zoran mentioned above that was part of it. Things I figured out:

1. Code must be double tabbed - you cannot use ```
2. Indented lists must also be double tabbed - I wasn't able to get a single tab to work
3. Images do not have to be tabbed - they can be in line with the above text
4. There should not be an empty line when an image follows a numbered list item BUT FOR CODE there must.

I still haven't completely figured out. mkdoc's behavior is not as predictable as regular markdown